# Trying to mutate array and object passed as parameters to an asynchronous function

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, mutating-function

So if you look at the code below you will see the following line fails with:

```
cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'forecasts' is a 'let' constant
```

caused by `forecasts.append(forecast)`. I have a service file which you see below called `ForecastService` and I am using the function to asynchronously grab JSON in my view controller from an API. I am trying to pass an object and an array of objects to the function which I then want to mutate on so I can use the updated values in my view controller to update my UI. I want to construct forecast objects and push them into the the array which I initialized in the view controller.

Any clarification on how I can get around this problem would be great.

```
import Foundation

import Alamofire

class ForecastService {

    static let sharedInstance = ForecastService()

    private init() {}

    func downloadForecastDetails(forecast: Forecast, forecasts: [Forecast], completed: @escaping DownloadComplete) {
        let url = URL(string: FORECAST_URL)!

        Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { response in
            let result = response.result.value

            if let dict = result as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                if let list = dict["list"] as? [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>] {

                    for obj in list {
                        let forecast = Forecast(weather: obj)
                        forecasts.append(forecast)
                    }
                }

            }

            completed()
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Just as it says, `forecasts` arrives as a `let` array, so you cannot append to it. You could assign it to a `var` so that you can append to it, but I cannot imagine what the point of that would be; it is, after all, a copy. Appending to it won't change the original array. You could work around that with `inout`, but the idea of doing that asynchronously is incoherent.

Comment: yes so i tried making it a var because it says swift uses let for params by default. I tried making it an inout param, but maybe I am not understanding that correctly

Comment: Add `var forecasts = forecasts` inside `downloadForecastDetails` to have a mutable array .

Comment: You need to pass the new array into the completion handler so that it can change the original.

Comment: @matt thanks for the comment I just ended up creating a new array inside the function as Mr.Bista suggested and then handed it to the completion handler as params.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the asynchronous block, but the mechanism of parameter `forecasts`. It's copied when you call the function, even if you declare it as var. Because Array is Swift is value type, it's the Swift's policy. (https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=10)
You can try to call `forecasts.append` outside the asynchronous block, it will still fail. So you need another way to pass a reference type (not value type) into the function.